# Comparing current date to multiple entry matrix date fields

Tags: entry, datetime, forloop

I need to display an entry only if the date fields within its Matrix are current. So, only display if the `startDate` is greater than or equal to today and the `endDate` is less than or equal to today.

Currently I have this code and am having trouble finding how to compare multiple dates.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionHandle') %}
    {% set present = now|date %}
    {% set entryStart = entry.matrixHandle.startDate %}
    {% set entryEnd = entry.matrixHandle.endDate %}

    {% if entryStart >= present and entryEnd <= present %}
        display entry information
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I'm guessing that I'm using the operators incorrectly or that "and" isn't allowed. Either way, it's not displaying anything and yes, I have a made sure that I have an entry with dates that would activate this if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've just got a logic problem.

```
{% if entryStart >= present and entryEnd <= present %}
```

The only way this will ever evaluate to `true` is if the `entryStart` and `entryEnd` DateTime fields have the exact same date and time (down to the second) that the present time is, which seems like a very small window.

You're essentially looking for an entry that lives in the future *and* in the past.

Comment: would changing it to {% if entryStart <= present and entryEnd >= present %} fix what I'm trying to do? Been working on these things for a while and just need another set of eyes to make sense of it.

Comment: Can you explain in words when you'd want the entry information to be shown.

Comment: your solution fixed this problem. my logic was just incorrect.